# ASP.NET code showing on browser along with Hello Word text in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have installed IIS on Windows 7 and I am having trouble with the ASP pages.

From the tutorial I am going through the whole code below gets displayed in the browser:

```
<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>
```

It is not displaying the Hello World! text it is displaying the code as it is above, how can I make this display correctly?

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head >
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post all your asp code please.

Comment: @Etch thats all the code

Comment: What's the extension of the document you're running? Make sure it's page.aspx, and not page.html or anything else.

Comment: @AaronS the file is .asp

Comment: change it to aspx for now, and see if that renders it.

Comment: Also, make sure you enabled BOTH asp and ASP.net in your windows features.

Comment: My computer looks like it doesnt recognise aspx files and notepad++ doesnt give me the option for aspx either

Comment: See my expanded answer below.

Answer (score 2):

When you install IIS after the .NET framework, often IIS is not properly configured to serve up ASP.NET pages.

Try running the `ASPNET_REGIIS -i` at a command prompt.

It is likely in the Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 or Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 directories.

You can learn more about ASPNET_REGIIS here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: I was about to add something along these lines to my answer but @NerdFury beat me too it.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this in command prompt but it says it is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable file or batch file.

Comment: You should have a visual studio command prompt that should have the proper path environment variable. But the easiest way is to navigate to the folder the executable exists in and run it from there. Try typing 'cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319' first and then type 'aspnet_regiis -i' on the command prompt. If you are running the 64bit operating system, then change the path above to be '%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v.4.0.30319'. Hope that helps.

Comment: that worked and it said installing asp, but the code still shows the same

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have no start `<body>` tag.

Actually you are missing alot.  more code to come!

**Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%
        Response.Write("Hello World!");
    %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok thanks, I accidently deleted the body tag but that still doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Hmmm.  I am not sure what to tell you then.  Are you getting any sort of error or are you just getting all the code displayed on the page?  This is as simple as it gets on the ASP.NET page seems like more information is needed.

Comment: did you enabled asp.net in windows features?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your answers so far that you're trying to run a classic ASP page, and not an ASP.net page.

By default, if your extension is .asp it's classic asp and .aspx will use the .net framework.

If you are trying to use classic asp you have to specifically enable it in windows 7.  [See here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/).

Answer (score 0):

Capital "R" in "reponse" - AND capital "W" in "write" :)

```
<%
Response.Write("Hello World!")
%>
```

or

```
<%= "Hello World!" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your'r URL does not begin with "file://" (in this case you are fetching the file from file system).
The URL should begin with http://localhost/ etc..

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.